# On-screen keyboard hiding the activity in android 3.1 (Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1) for Listview

Tags: android, user-interface, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard

I would like to have a

ListView
Two EditTexts
A button

in my activity so that whenever I type into either of the edittexts and press the button, the input is displayed in the ListView. The problem I have is that as soon as I start editing the first EditText, the on-screen keyboard pops up and hides the second EditText and the button. What is the way to have all the layout components on screen while also having the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft), in particular adjustResize.